# What are proper tests for analyzing choice between two options?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, count-data, methodology

For surveys with the following responses, what are the appropriate statistical methods to analyze the data?

The goal is to find which lists ultimately users prefer following several questions asking for various aspects comparing the two lists.

For example, one of the questions asks: Comparing lists x and y, which list do you prefer?

1. very much x more than y
2. somehow x more than y
3. about the same
4. somehow y more than x
5. very much y more than x

A between-subject study design compares three lists x, y, and z randomly two per user, i.e., user 1 compares x and y, user 2 compares y and z, and user 3 compares x and z , etc.

Now I want to find out which list ultimately is the best among all.

I have never dealt with such a combined response format. What is the correct way to analyze this? Can you give a reference?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there were a standard approach. You need to set up a model that somehow specifies how the "best" list is connected to a probability distribution for what people will respond. This is not trivial. There are such models for binary preference data, which could serve as a starting point (I'm not aware of such things with a 5-point scale), see https://www.shivani-agarwal.net/Publications/2016/ijcai16-ranking-choice-models-invited.pdf

Comment: Maybe something simpler can be done if you have only three lists, but I'd still think something tailor-made would need to be developed for your situation.

Comment: Can you help me figure out which direction should I go? I only have three conditions. To simplify, if we take only one condition, comparing x and y, what is the proper statistical method for finding if x is better than y?

Comment: Sorry, to me this looks like a proper advisory job, nothing to be solved easily on a forum like this. (Maybe others have more time to put into a more detailed answer.) You may of course group your answers to yes/no/no preference and then use what is mentioned in the paper cited above, but that will waste some information.